# Using set theory to prove a function problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

[image]

I begin with:

$$A = \{a \le x < x_0  | f(x) = 0  \}$$

$$B = \{x_0 < x \le b | f(x) = 0   \}$$

Let $c = \sup A$ and let $d = \sup B$

First to prove $f(x)  > 0$ for $x \in (c, d)$ I will use contradiction.

Assume $f(x) < 0$. We have $c \ge x_0 > x$ by definition of supremum.

For set $A$ we have: $x < x_0$ so $f(x) < 0 < f(x_0)$ then by IVT there exists an $x_1$ such that: $x < x_1 < x_0$ and $f(x_1) = 0$. And hence $x_1 < c = \sup S$ which is a contradiction, since $x_1$ is the new $\sup$.

Assume $f(x) = 0$. Immediate contradiction like the above.

Secondly, lets prove $f(x) > 0$ in set B.

Assume $f(x) < 0$ then, since $x_0 < x$ we have $f(x_0) > 0 > f(x)$. By IVT, there exists a point $x_3$ such that $x_0 < x_3 < x$ and $f(x_3) = 0$.  and $x_3 < x \le d = \sup B$ A contradiction.

Last part is  proving $f(c) = f(d) = 0$. Which is the hardest.

Lets assume $f(c) > 0$ then, $f(c) - \epsilon < f(x) < f(c) + \epsilon$ for $|x -c| < \delta \implies c - \delta < x < c + \delta$ This means $f(x) > 0$ in $x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta)$. So will this be a contradiction because of $c = \sup A$ then it must be $0$??

Please advice!?

Comment: What book is that and what is the "previous exercise"

Comment: You probably mean $d = \inf B$.

Comment: @Timbuc, Spivak Calculus. The previous exercise said: "show that there is a largest $x$ in [a, b] with f(x) = 0". But I dont see how to prove that?

Comment: @PedroM. no I meant $d = \sup B$

Comment: Hum, $d = \sup B$ won't work for this problem. Actually, after reading a bit more carefully I discovered some mistakes which may or may not be typos, for instance: you wrote that for $x \in (c,d)$ we have $c \geq x_0 > x$ (which is clearly not true) and that $x_1 < c$ would be a contradiction (also not true, $x_1 > c$ would be contradiction if $c$ is the sup).

Comment: Why? Isnt $c$ the least upper bound? If $x_1 < c$ isnt $x_1$ now the least upper bound?

Comment: Finding an element $x_1 \in A$ such that $x_1 < c$ does not disqualify $c$ as the upper bound, as there might exist $x_1 < x_2 < c$ such that $x_2 \in A$. In any case, since you said $x \in (c,d)$, we automatically have $x > c$.

Comment: nonono, I meant $c$ will not be the supremum anymore, its still an upperbound, but NOT the LEAST upper bound.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20640/discussion-between-pedro-m-and-amad27).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am following your idea.

$$A = \{a \le x < x_0  | f(x) = 0  \}$$

$$B = \{x_0 < x \le b | f(x) = 0   \}$$

Let $c = \sup A$ and let $d = \inf B$ ($\sup B$ doesn't work here, since it's always $b$). Note $c<x_0<d$

Step 1: prove $f(x)  > 0$ for $x \in (c, d)$ we will use contradiction.

Assume $f(x) < 0$, for some $c<x<d$, by IVT there exists an $x_1$ such that: $x < x_1 < x_0$ and $f(x_1) = 0$. And hence $x_1\in A,x_1 > c = \sup A$ which is a contradiction, since in this case $c$ is not an upper bound .

Assume $f(x) = 0$. Immediate contradiction like the above.

Part 2: Show $f(c)=f(d)=0$, if it's true, we are done.

Suppose $f(c)>0$, then by your argument, we know $f(x) > 0$ in $x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta)$, then $c-\frac{1}{2}\delta$ is also a upper bound for $A$, which contradict the definition of $\sup$(the least).

More details about above argument.You have shown $x\in (c,x_0]$, $f(x)>0$. You have also shown $f(x) > 0$ in $x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta)$, in particular, we have $f(x) > 0$ in $x \in (c - \frac{1}{2}\delta, x_0)$. By your definition of $A$, can there be any point $x\in A$, such that $x>c - \frac{1}{2}\delta$?

If $f(c)<0$, then by intermediate value theorem, $\exists x_1$, st. $c<x_1<x_0$, s.t. $f(x_1)=0$ hence contradicts the $\sup$ (the upper bounded of $A$).

Hence we have $f(c)=0$

Comment: How is $c - \frac{1}{2} \delta$ an upperbound? +!

Comment: @Amad27 because there is no $x\in (c-\frac{1}{2}\delta, x_0)$, such that $f(x)=0$, hence all $x\in A$ has $x\le c-\frac{1}{2}\delta$

Comment: How can $c - \frac{1}{2}\delta$ be in Set $A$ if $f(x) \ne 0$?

Comment: In other words, how do you show $x \le c - \frac{1}{2} \delta$ for all $x$ in the set?

Comment: @Amad27 $c-\frac{1}{2}\delta$ isn't in $A$. I have added more details in the answer.

Comment: To your question in the second paragraph. The answer is no because $f(x) > 0$ for $x \in (c - \frac{1}{2}\delta, x_0)$ so no element $x > c - \frac{1}{2} \delta$ can be there because $f(x) \ne 0$ for $x \in (c - \frac{1}{2}\delta, x_0)$ correct?

Comment: @Amad27 Yes. So it's an upper bound of $A$.

Comment: What about the things that Pedro M. is saying are wrong?